# Blockchain Performance Metrics

Tags: blockchain

How can I measure blockchain execution time, latency and throughput?
Which API do I use to measure?
Anyone suggest any article or book for me to read about the blockchain performance metrics?

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is EtheScan charts:

https://etherscan.io/charts